# How can I make onClick() not trigger when I click another onClick() inside of it?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a child (deletePost button) inside of this div. The problem is that when I click it, the parent gets clicked too. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
{!this.state.userSelectionArea &&
            this.state.jobData.data.map(data => {
              if (data.urgent !== "true") {
                return (

                  <div
                    onClick={e => this.showModalJob(data.id)}
                    className="postData"
                    key={data.id}
                  >
                  {data.facebookid === this.state.user.id &&
                      <button onClick={this.deletePost} className="deletePostButton">
                      <i className="fa fa-close" />
                      </button>}
                    <p>
                      <span className="postConnector">
                        {" "}
                        {this.context.main.seeking3}{" "}
                      </span>
                      <span className="posterGoal">{data.jobtype}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p className="postArea">{data.area}</p>
                    <div className="postMoment">
                      <Moment fromNow>{data.created_at}</Moment>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                );
              }
            })}
```

Comment: Why is the delete button inside of the showModal button?

Answer (score 3):

[Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) will prevent the click event from bubbling up and firing the parent's click event.

```
childAction = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Action
}

<button onClick={ e => this.childAction(e) }>Next Action</button>
```